# searchkit: RefinementListFilter can't access certain data in json

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, searchkit

I'm usig searchkit as part of a website, but have problems in accessing my data that's been converted into json format previously.
My json directory looks like this:

```
(...)
hits:
   0:
    _index:           content
    _type:            content
    _source:      
          meta:
             author:  content
(...)
```

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzvhA.png)

and I'm using RefinementListFilter (in ReactDOM.render) and this works fine:

```
<RefinementListFilter id="index" title="Index" field={"_index"}/>
<RefinementListFilter id="Type" title="Type" field={"_type"}/>
```

whereas i can't seem to access the content that is written under author:

```
<RefinementListFilter id="Author" title="Author" field={"_source.meta.author"}/>
```

this doesn't work (no error, nothing happens when I type this), although when i use **_source.meta.author** in this context it works like expected:

```
class SearchHit extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const result = this.props.result;
      return (
        <div className={this.props.bemBlocks.item("author")}> <b> Index: </b> {result._index} </div>
        <div className={this.props.bemBlocks.item("author")}> <b> Author: </b> {result._source.meta.author} </div>
      )}}
```

What am I doing wrong? The first and last snippet work just fine, it's just the middle one that doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within the field indices of your elasticsearch instance. 
According to the [docs](http://docs.searchkit.co/v0.10.0/docs/server/indexing.html), Searchkit needs two different kinds of indexed fields for searching and filtering.

In your case it seems like the field `author` is not indexed correctly.

To solve this, you need to change the elasticsearch mapping for the field author:

```
    ...
    "meta": {
      "properties": {
        "author": {
          "type": "text", 
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
    ...
```

You can then access the authors in the Refinementfilter via

```
<RefinementListFilter id="author" title="Author" field={"meta.author.raw"}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to restructure your JSON file for distinct clarification. You need two different fields for searching and filtering.

```
"meta": {
      "properties": {
        "author": {
          "type": "text", 
            "fields": {
                "val": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
```

While in a Refinementfilter, it can be accessed this way

```
<RefinementListFilter id="Author" title="Author" field={"meta.author.val"}/>
```